# How to assign 'return' as shortcut for anchor

Tags: javascript, html, keyboard-shortcuts, anchor

Is it possible to assign the return key as a shortcut for an anchor. Just like when submitting a form if one of the input fields are on focus.
I have looked a little at the jQuery hotkeys but since I'm lacking some skills in js I can't quite figure it out.

My plan is that when the page loads the user can just press enter. Then an action will be performed followed by a redirect. I'm trying to do this

Reason for doing this is that I believe it's a lot faster for the user to press enter than to move the cursor and click on the link before the actual action takes place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Much more simple will be to auto focus the link:

```
window.onload = function() {
    document.getElementById("changeStatusLink").focus();
}
```

No jQuery is required and as it's focused, Enter press will trigger the click event.

Comment: @Pet yes as far as I know all browsers as it's pretty much "core" JavaScript. One downside worth noting is that it won't "support" more than one `onload` events like jQuery does.

Comment: since that specific page only needs one `onload` function so far I'll go with this. This seems by far as the most simple solution. So thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If it's a form (e.g. with id `#myform`) why not to try to trap the user submit using this code. You need to put a hidden form submit element inside the form.

**HTML**

```
<form id="myform">
  <input type="text" name="email" />
  <input type="submit" style="display: hidden;" />
  <a href="" id="myform">Click here to do some action</a>
</form>
```

**Javascript**

```
$(function(){
    $('#myform').submit(function(){
        $(this); // this refers to the form
        $('#your-link-id').click();
        return false;
    });
});
```

**See**: [Bind an event handler to the "submit" JavaScript event, or trigger that event on an element.](http://api.jquery.com/submit/)

Note: the code is untested but it should work.

Comment: But since I'm not working with a form I think I gonna go with Shadow Wizard's approach :) But thank you very much. I might need this a little later anyway :P

Comment: @nickifrandsen You can just add a form :D, it never affect the look.